# Dynamically injecting an <object> tag causes white flash

Tags: javascript, html, dom, code-injection, object-tag

I'm trying to dynamically insert some HTML/JS/CSS on command. (holding 
off this code for page loading speed). I found a neat way 
of doing this, inserting a HTML5  tag pointing at the html- 
file which in turn references the css and js, like so:

```
function toggleObject() { 
var object = document.getElementById('myObject'); 
  if (!object) { 
    var e = document.createElement('object'); 
    e.setAttribute('data', 'testing.html'); 
    e.setAttribute('id', 'myObject'); 
    // inject data into DOM 
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(e); 
 } else { 

    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].removeChild(object); 
}}
```

The only problem with this is that upon inserting the tag the object (height, width and position as defined by css) flashes white before loading which isn't very attractive.

Is there a remedy for the ugly white flash?

Note! I experimented with toggling the visibility property of the object and firing up a loader div, but I can't figure what event would be able to call off the loader and turn visibility back on when the object is fully injected in the DOM. In end I settled for just a timeout of 1 sec, which feels less than optimal..

Comment: Have you tried: http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/

Comment: Really? A Flash Player embedding plugin? I don't quite see how that helps. And I'd rather not use any plugins..

Comment: Ever think: maybe some has encountered this problem before and has fixed it, and wrote some code and posted it for others to use, for free. BTW - it's not a plug-in, it's a JavaScript library.

Comment: Ok, maybe I didn't read far enough. Thanks. Still seems a bit overkill  with a library (yes, its tiny but so is my mobile web-app)

Comment: @Diodeus SWFObject won't help you with that problem at all. It's a cross-browser library for embedding a Flash player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the *visibility* to *hidden* when you create the `OBJECT` `Element` and then setting it to *visible* once it has been appended to its parent `Node`.

Comment: Is there an event or something I can use for setting it to visible once its been fully loaded?

Comment: You can register a *load* `EventListener` on `OBJECT` `Element`s; this might however not be reliable. What kind of data source are you loading with that `OBJECT` (e.g. Flash player)?

Comment: I might give that a go. I'm loading an html-file.

Comment: No, its the same. That's not a bad idea, I'll look into it. Thanks. What would be the benefit you think?

Comment: Is this cross-domain? If not you could easily use *XHR* (*XMLHttpRequest*).

Comment: Yeah cross-domain, sorry. The benefit is that it's the established pattern for retrieving data from your own domain. :-)

Comment: and it'll have some nice events. Great, that's much better.